# My WordPress theme style.css override admin theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I create a new WordPress theme in WordPress latest version 4.5.1. and some theme css override in admin theme. How can I block this css for admin area?

Comment: How did you add the theme css? The proper way to add scripts and styles to your theme is to enqueue them in the `functions.php` files.  More info here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/.

Answer (score 1):

Use wp_enqueue_style to add css/js to front end.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_style', 'some_hook_function'):
```

Use admin_enqueue_scripts to add css/js to back end.

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'some_hook_function'):
```